# graphic.addAnimation calling addAnimation

Tags: java, arguments, processing

I run this code:

```
graphic.addAnimation("standart",new int[] {0,1},1.0,true);
```

which calls the graphic.addAnimation(String,int[],float,boolean) Method:

```
public void addAnimation(String nme,int[] frmes,float time,boolean loop) {
    animations.push(new Aim(nme, frmes, time, loop));
}
```

but I get this error:

> the function addAnimation(String,int[],float,boolean) does not exist.

SpriteSheet:

```
package progame;

import java.util.Stack;

import processing.core.PImage;

public class SpriteSheet extends Graphic {
    public int height,width,index;
    public int timer;
    public String playing;
    public Stack<PImage> sheet = new Stack<PImage>();
    public Stack<Aim> animations = new Stack<Aim>();
    
    public SpriteSheet(String path,int h,int w) {
        super(path);
        height = h;
        width = w;
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.floor(source.height/height); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < Math.floor(source.width/width); j++) {
                sheet.push(source.get(j*width, i*height, width, height));
            }
        }
    }
    
    public SpriteSheet(String path,Entity e,int h,int w) {
        super(path,e);
        height = h;
        width = w;
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.floor(source.height/height); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < Math.floor(source.width/width); j++) {
                sheet.push(source.get(j*width, i*height, width, height));
            }
        }
    }
    
    public Aim getAnimation(String name) {
        for(int i = 0; i< animations.size(); i++)
        {
            if(animations.get(i).name == name) {
                return(animations.get(i));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public void play(String name) {
        for(int i = 0; i< animations.size(); i++)
        {
            if(animations.get(i).name == name) {
                playing = name;
                index = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }else
            {
                playing = null;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void update() {
        timer ++;
        Aim aim = getAnimation(playing);
        if( timer > aim.frameRate)
        {
            timer = 0;
            if(index == aim.frames.length)
            {
                if(aim.looping) {
                    index = 0;
                }else
                {
                    playing = null;
                }
            }else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        source = sheet.get(index);
    }
    
    public void render() {
        update();
        super.render();
    }
    
    public void addAnimation(String nme,int[] frmes,float time,boolean loop) {
        animations.push(new Aim(nme, frmes, time, loop));
    }
    
    private class Aim
    {
        String name;
        int[] frames;
        float frameRate;
        boolean looping;
        public Aim(String nme,int[] frmes,float time,boolean loop)
        {
            name = nme;
            frames = frmes;
            frameRate = time;
            looping = loop;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the declaration of Class of which `addAnimation(...)` is a member. Also post the declaration of `graphic` variable.

Comment: The value `1.0` is a double not a float, so I don't believe you have exactly the situation you describe. You need to check your details again to see eactly what the problem is.

Comment: I've never heard Java call anything a "function".

Comment: lol, sorry messed that up xP its a method.. just been messing around in flash and pyhton lately..

Comment: @ssapkota `graphic = new SpriteSheet("test.png",this,8,8);`

Comment: Yes, but the fact that it says "function" in your question means that you're not providing us with the *actual* error message that you get. Could you supply that?

Comment: @TheBreadCat - Post the whole line of declaration. Is it `SpriteSheet graphic = ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said

> its declared in the Entity class, like this: public Graphic graphic;

Declare it as:

```
public SpriteSheet graphic;
```

Comment: hmmm, i just thought that if you declared a varible as a super class it would be able to be defined as one of its children.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you obtain the instance 'graphic' from in the following line?

`graphic.addAnimation("standart",new int[] {0,1},1.0,true);`

Or more importantly, what is its declaration? You can't call `addAnimation` on a variable of type `Graphic`. As it's `SpriteSheet` that defined this method.

Comment: its declared in the Entity class, like this: `public Graphic graphic;`

Comment: @TheBreadCat - And the `Graphic` class does not have an `addAnimation` method?

Comment: no but since its defined as a SpriteSheet(wich extends Graphic) the graphic variable should have.

Comment: I'm sorry, but Java doesn't work that way. If a variable is declared as a super class of something, you can't access methods of its sub classes. Think about this for a second. A single super can have many sub classes, each having unique methods. How can the compiler know without any context what the actual sub type is going to be that will be assigned at runtime? If you want to call sub type methods, you need a ***down cast***, declare directly as sub class, or add the sub class method to the super class (so sub then overrides it).

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's comment: `its declared in the Entity class, like this: public Graphic graphic;`

`((SpriteSheet)graphic).addAnimation("standart",new int[] {0,1},1.0,true);`

would fix the problem.